# error: request for member in which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, class

**error: request for member in which is of non-class type**

main.cpp|17|error: request for member 'setName' in 'studentOne', which is of non-class type 'Student()'

the error is on the last line

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    public:
        Student(string name,string program,int age);
        void setName(string);
        void setProgram(string);
        void setAge(int);
        string getName();
        string getProgram();
        int getAge();

    private:
        string Name;
        string Program;
        int Age;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H

#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student::Student(string name,string program,int age)
{
    setName(name);
    setProgram(program);
    setAge(age);
}
void Student::setName(string name)
{
    Name = name;

}
string Student::getName()
{
    return Name;
}

void Student::setProgram(string program)
{
    Program = program;
}
string Student::getProgram()
{
    return Name;
}

void Student::setAge(int age)
{
    Age = age;
}
int Student::getAge()
{
    return Age;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string studentName;
    string studentProgram;
    int studentAge;

    Student studentOne();

    cout << "Welcome to the Student input Wizard";
    getline(cin, studentName);
    cout << endl;

    studentOne.setName(studentName);


}
```

am trying to call the member functions of the class in the main function to input the data for the variable name the others and to print the output.

But every member function I try to call brings about that error, tried the suggestion that I should removes the braces at the end of the object but the the error shows up on that line too.

Comment: studentOne is function declaration. Read up on most vexing parse.

Comment: The error *should* disappear if you write `Student studentOne;` instead. Otherwise your compiler is massively broken.